# dlib object detection always return zero results on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, object-detection, dlib

I have been using dlib object detection successfully on mac. Now I want to use it in an iOS app. However, after spending countless hours, dlib object detector always returns zero rectangles.

```
        ifstream fin(dataDir + "/object_detector.svm", ios::binary);
        typedef dlib::scan_fhog_pyramid<dlib::pyramid_down<6> > image_scanner_type;
        dlib::object_detector<image_scanner_type> detector;
        dlib::deserialize(detector, fin);

        vector<dlib::rectangle> dets = detector(dlibImage);
```

To make sure it’s not due to a different image, I am using exact same image for which detector returns 1 hit on mac. I have also printed uchar from part of the image in both mac and iOS, and it’s returning same values. So image data is exactly the same.

Probably dlib library is not built correctly for iOS. I have tried multiple approaches for this. From /example/build dir, below command was invoked.

```
    cmake -G Xcode ..
    cmake --build . --config Release
```

It generated dlib.xcodeproj project in dlib_build dir. I opened the project in xcode, changed architecture to iOS (armv7, arm64) and rebuild the library. This library was linked to my project. I got zero results with this approach. dlib was built in debug mode; I did not get any assertion errors.

Second approach tried was to use dlib/all/source.app in my project. I used all the proprocessing flags that are used by cmake or dlib.xcodeproj project. No errors, but still no matches.

I have compared build settings of my xcode project with examples.xcodeproj generated by cmake and it’s same. Also checked the xcode project from https://github.com/zweigraf/face-landmarking-ios, but no help.

Strange thing is detector takes couple of seconds to process and comes back with zero matches. So it’s doing something. I wish there was a debug logging that I can turn on for the detector.

I am out of ideas. Will appreciate if anyone can help. dlib is a wonderful library, I just wish it would have been easier to work with on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

dlib is working fine on iOS too. Kicking myself for it, but I mixed up the detector instances. The detector on which I called below line was not used for object detection.

```
dlib::deserialize(detector, fin);
```

I was just using an empty detector instance, and it was returning 0 detections. By empty detector, I mean it was defined but deserialize method was not invoked. It would have been nice if dlib returned an error or warning, if a detector not loaded with object_detector.svm file is used for detection.

I have observed the same behavior with shape detector too. If sp.dat is not loaded, it silently reports 0 parts detected. Posting this as answer, in case someone else also makes such a silly mistake.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to build object detector using dlib, do you have any guidance regarding this. As Its very new to me , just struggling how to train model with specific object image  and use it in to detect object in other images.  If you provide me some tutorial or blog for my better understanding that will be appreciated. Thanks!